# How to control when `less` rings the (audio or "visual") bell

Tags: less, bell

`less` gives alerts by ringing the bell (by default) or flashing the display (called the "visual bell," when using the -q or -Q option).  Some common situations where it emits this alert are trying to scroll up past the top of the file, or searching for a regular expression that appears on the topmost currently displayed line.

The problem is, one of these is a legitimate error condition -- I am trying to do something impossible -- while the other communicates no useful information: `less` already highlights search terms that it finds, and already positions the window so that the first such term is on the top line of the file, so this alert is just telling me "hey, I did what you asked," which (IMO) never warrants an alert.

I know `less` is very customizable beyond the command-line options, but I so far haven't found any way to disable non-error alerts while retaining legitimate error ones.  Is there a way to specify in which situations you want an alert?

Answer (score 2):

The only configurable feature for `less` with the bell is the command-line option **`-q`** (and its third state **`-Q`**).  The [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less) says:

> **`-q`** or **`--quiet`** or **`--silent`**
>
> Causes moderately "quiet" operation: the terminal bell is not rung if an attempt is made to scroll past the end of the file or before the beginning of the file. If the terminal has a "visual bell", it is used instead. The bell will be rung on certain other errors, such as typing an invalid character. The default is to ring the terminal bell in all such cases.
>
> **`-Q`** or **`--QUIET`** or **--SILENT**
>
> Causes totally "quiet" operation: the terminal bell is never rung.

(For what it's worth, reading the source code — which I did — is the way to know what it actually does).